# NetBeans remote project with svn

Tags: windows, svn, netbeans, remote-access, remote-server

I have a remote project which I use for my work; this is on a Debian OPS and I access it through SSL. The project is on the remote machine under SVN control.

Is there a way for me to connect NetBeans to the repository and commit to it directly?

Does the option "Import into svn repository remote project" allow that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes just checkout the project right from NetBeans

Follow the steps

- Open netbeans and click on team menu in toolbar
- From team menu select subversion and select checkout.
- Once your checkout is done then it asks you to create project
  locally,Please do create it
- Then, it automatically sync up with your repository in remote server.

Comment: I dont get you. you only get the connection via svn not the remote acess... How do you make it sync with the remote repository???
I need to have svn and remote acess asyncron... i need the svn for team work and conflict solving, and the remote acess for my machine.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, i figured it out :3

Here  is how you can hack netbeans to have svn and remote in same project

1. connect to your remote server, pull the whole project.

   - it will be located somwhere in your user files like documents/netbeanprojects/name of the project.
2. Now go the folder and check out the repo from the original svn server...
3. DONE you have svn with remote :3

(laugh evilly)